# Trying to scrape business website from webpage with R

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am attempting to scrape the website link:

https://www.anelegantaffairbridal.com/?utm_source=theknot.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=theknot

from the Contact for Appointment Popup on
https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/an-elegant-affair-cedar-falls-ia-537984 using R Studio.

I have tried

```
page <- read_html("https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/an-elegant-affair-cedar-falls-ia-537984")
Website <- html_attr(html_nodes(page,xpath = '//*[@id="appointment-vendors-categories"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/span/a'),"href")
```

This is my output: character(0).
The desired output is: https://www.anelegantaffairbridal.com/?utm_source=theknot.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=theknot

I successfully scraped info from the contact section at the bottom of the page using the code below, but the same method doesn't seem to be working for the link.

```
Name_of_Vendor2 <- substr((page %>% html_nodes("h3") %>% html_text),18,70)

Phone_of_Vendor <- html_text(html_nodes(page, xpath = "//div[@class = 'contact-info--900c8 body1--711dc']/span[2]"))

Address_of_Vendor <- html_text(html_nodes(page, xpath = "//div[@class = 'contact-info--900c8 body1--711dc']/span[1]"))
```

Comment: I am trying to parse out the specific business link( 1st link) from their page on the knot (2nd link). I am just trying to output the Business Name, Phone, Address, and Website. I am able to get the first three, but I having trouble parsing out the website url https://www.anelegantaffairbridal.com/?utm_source=theknot.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=theknot from the html code

Comment: apparently the link loads up after javascript run cuz i tried every selector possible even `html_nodes(page, xpath = '//a[contains(@href,"http://www.AnElegantAffairBridal.com")]')` returns `{xml_nodeset (0)}`

Comment: So it wouldn't be possible to parse out the weblink? Or would I have to use a different package in R in order to load the data first and then download the html code

Comment: wait I think I'm unto something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look into the downloaded html by writing it into a file using `rvest::write_xml(page, file="temp.html")`. I then proceeded to search for the URL and found it in the one of the last `script` tags as a `JSON` object, and the key for the url is `websiteUrl`. So I selected the last script tag and ran a regular expression on it's content to get the `URL`

```r
scripts <- html_nodes(page,xpath = '//script[@type="text/javascript"]')
script <-  html_text(scripts[[length(scripts)-1]])

stringr::str_extract(script,'(?<="websiteUrl":").+?(?=")')
#> [1] "http://www.AnElegantAffairBridal.com?utm_source=theknot.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=theknot"
```